# How to handle pivot table error when a field is missing?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot

I wrote a macro that includes creating several pivot tables from monthly reports.

The reports do not always have all the fields which need to be filtered.

The macro gives the error

> Object doesn't support this property or method.

Is there a way to include an IF statement within the table formatting commands so that it will skip fields that are missing?

The debug error message refers to the line: `If HasPivotItem(.PivotFields("PH Rel Independent Risk Unit Credit Organization")`

```
Dim PT As Excel.PivotTable
    Set PT = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
            "Raw Data!R1C1:R480C37", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable( _
            TableDestination:="'Pivot of Certain Data'!R1C1", TableName:="Pivot of Certain Data", _
            DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14)

    With PT
     With .PivotFields( _
        "field 1")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
     End With
    With .PivotFields( _
        "field 1")
        .PivotItems("item 1").Visible = False
        
        If HasPivotItem(.PivotFields("field 1"), "item 2") Then
        .PivotFields("field 1").PivotItems("item 2").Visible = False
        End If
        
        .PivotItems("item 3").Visible = False
   End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a function like this to check if the item exists:

```
Private Function HasPivotItem(ByRef pField As PivotField, ByVal Item As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    HasPivotItem = Not IsNull(pField.PivotItems(Item))
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

And use it like:

```
Dim PT As Excel.PivotTable
Set PT = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Raw Data!R1C1:R480C37", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable( _
        TableDestination:="'Pivot of Certain Data'!R1C1", TableName:="Pivot of Certain Data", _
        DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14)

With PT.PivotFields("field 1")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1

    .PivotItems("item 1").Visible = False

    If HasPivotItem(PT.PivotFields("field 1"), "item 2") Then
        .PivotItems("item 2").Visible = False
    End If

    .PivotItems("item 3").Visible = False
End With
```

Comment: @PEH I tried your suggestion, but it gave a compile error: 'Sub or Function not defined.' The error was in reference to ```If HasPivotItem(**PivotFields**("field 1"), "item 2") ```

Comment: @GarrettBremer I missed the `.` infront of `.PivotFields` to make it use your `With` block. By bad, fixed it.

Comment: @PEH Oh, I missed that too! I added it in, but now it's giving me an error for that whole line: 'Object doesn't support this property or method.'

Comment: @GarrettBremer well, can you edit your original question and add the code you are using?

Comment: @PEH I adjusted my original question to include more of the code. I hope this helps clarify how it all fits together.

Comment: @GarrettBremer you got the `With` statements a bit mixed up. Check my edit.

Comment: @PEH That worked! Thank you so much for your help. I have a lot of With statements to consolidate now. Every day teaches something new.

Comment: @GarrettBremer Try to avoid nested `With` statements if possible, it gets messy quickly.